Hamburger Menu not working properly with iOS
Hamburger Menu works on desktop, does not work well on iOS when scrolling down the page.
Tested site on iPhone, Hamburger menu works properly until you scroll too far down the page or too quickly.
Once you refresh the page the Hamburger Menu will work properly.

Probably your question about responsive web site working on iphone or ipad browsers, right?  There are one more browsers working on ios devices. Chrome, Firefox, and Opera are available to work on ios devices like Safari. Which browsers did you test? Your issue seems to be related js hamburger menu framework.
